How to Integrate PowerApps with Dynamics AX?
Question:
Hi,I am working on a process that requires integrating PowerApps with Dynamics AX, and I'm looking for the best way to achieve this.
Here’s the scenario:

I have a PowerApps screen with a form.
The user fills out the form, and upon submission, the data needs to be passed to Dynamics AX.
Dynamics AX should then generate a PDF based on the data received - (or on click of button).
Once the PDF is generated, I need to send it back to PowerApps for the user to access.

I've come across a few potential options for integration, but the process is not clearly explained:
API Integration: I have seen some API integration options between PowerApps and Dynamics AX. Can I use APIs to pass the data to AX, generate the PDF, and return it to PowerApps? If so, what would the step-by-step process look like?
SQL Integration: If we connect PowerApps to a SQL database, pass the data from PowerApps to SQL, and then have SQL communicate with Dynamics AX to generate the PDF? How can this flow be managed, and can SQL handle PDF generation, or would it need additional services?
What are the best practices for this type of integration, and which method (API, SQL, or any other) would be the most efficient for my use case?
Any guidance or instructions would be greatly appreciated!

I have removed the  tag since this isn't related to the SQL language. Perhaps you want to add a dbms tag for the SQL database you plan to use? (There are dozens of them.)

If Dynamics AX is locally hosted then you can simply create a on-premises data gateway and then use it to read/write data directly on SQL through a Canvas App. Check this link  below, it has some good detail. https://medium.com/@mannanak/integrating-power-apps-with-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-cf3a773d05a7
